# метод Монте-Карло для разного количества точек в R

Tags: r, монте-карло

Задание: дан квадрат [-1,1]*[-1,1] с центром в (0, 0), в него попадает 10000 точек. Требуется оценить число пи и построить график зависимости числа пи от числа бросков.

По методу Монте-Карло нахожу пи исходя из вписанной окружности:

```
x = runif(n, -1, 1)
y = runif(n, -1, 1)
circle = (sqrt(x^2 + y^2)) <= 1 
p = sum(circle) / 10000
p
#вероятность попадания точки в круг
pi2 = 4 * p * 1
#искомое число пи
pi2
```

таким образом методом монте-карло при 10000 повторений у нас получается приближенное пи, далее нам надо оценить сколько будет равно пи при разном количестве повторений, например, при 100.000, 1.000.000 и далее.
Вопрос: как сделать этот код без цикла и apply, могу только предположить что если вручную набирать n2 = 100.000, n3 = 1.000.000 и так далее, но это точно не верное решение, а дальше просто взять все эти значения pi.est2, pi.est3 и тд при разных n  и построить зависимость этих значений от n, но наверняка есть другой способ, только я не могу понять, как изначально задать в таком случае n и написать код без циклов и apply, чтобы в конце выводилось 10000 значений пи при 1, 2, ... 10000 бросках, и можно было построить график зависимости этих пи от количества бросков.

Answer (score 0):

Если условие буквально так и звучит - без цикла и `apply()` - то достаточно заменить `apply()` на `sapply()`/`lapply()`/`Map()`.